# Convert DataFrame Column's String to other Columns like a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I Have a dataframe with like this:

```
  id                contact
0  101   {"ref": 201, "name": "Alejandro"}
1  102   {"ref": 202, "name": "Betty"}  
2  103   {"ref": 203, "name": "Jose"}
3  104   {"ref": 204, "name": "Alek"}
4  105   {"ref": 205, "name": "Daniela"}
```

...

The contact column is a string column and I want to transform to Dictonary and then add a column ref and a column called name to the DataFrame...

Comment: how did you got this dataframe on the beginning? maybe there should be faster way to reinitialize it...

Comment: try this in a lambda: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

```py
import pandas as pd


d = {
    'ID': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
    'contact': [{"ref": 201, "name": "Alejandro"},
                {"ref": 202, "name": "Betty"},
                {"ref": 203, "name": "Jose"},
                {"ref": 204, "name": "Alek"},
                {"ref": 205, "name": "Daniela"}]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2 = pd.concat([df, df['contact'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

print(df2)

    ID                            contact  ref       name
0  101  {'ref': 201, 'name': 'Alejandro'}  201  Alejandro
1  102      {'ref': 202, 'name': 'Betty'}  202      Betty
2  103       {'ref': 203, 'name': 'Jose'}  203       Jose
3  104       {'ref': 204, 'name': 'Alek'}  204       Alek
4  105    {'ref': 205, 'name': 'Daniela'}  205    Daniela
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.loads()` to convert the strings into a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import json 


dic = dict(df['contact'])

ref = []
name = []

for key, val in dic.items():
    x = json.loads(val)
    ref.append(x['ref'])
    name.append(x['name'])

df['ref'] = ref
df['name'] = name

df
```

Output:

```
    id      contact                             ref     name
0   101     {"ref": 201, "name": "Alejandro"}   201     Alejandro
1   102     {"ref": 202, "name": "Betty"}       202     Betty
2   103     {"ref": 203, "name": "Jose"}        203     Jose
3   104     {"ref": 204, "name": "Alek"}        204     Alek
4   101     {"ref": 205, "name": "Daniela"}     205     Daniela
```